# Handle API calls after access token expires

Tags: ios, swift, token

I am working on an application where we are going to introduce `token expiry`. The token is going to expire every night at `12.00 am`. I have few questions in my mind as to how can we handle token expiry in the app.

What I have done:-

> Whenever the app is launched, I look for the token in `NSUserDefaults`
> and check if it is still valid or not. If it is not valid then I call
> token refresh API and store the new token. After that, every API calls
> is called with the new token.

Question in my mind:-

> One user is using the app at 11.59, he is on app's homepage,
> now its 12.01 and user moves into the 2nd page of the app, where I am
> calling 3 different API requests. First API request gives me the
> status code as `401`, so I call token refresh API. In between other 2
> requests might also get called and they too have called refresh token
> API.
>
> How can I make sure as soon as I get `401`, invalidate all API calls till I don't have token refreshed?

Comment: As far as i know, you cannot invalidate a request after its been called, i think the best practice is to check for validity of the token before every request is made

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why you would have a hard time for token expiry, usually tokens expire after a sliding scale (say after 24 hours) not hard stop.

In any case, the easiest way is to have one helper function to obtain the token it reads it from NSUserDefaults, you call it on app start and before every API call. The first call validates the token also stores expiration time, so that the next time you call this function you know if the token should have expired or not without calling the server to validate again. It's a lot better than making a lot of failed requests to the server since you know they would fail.
That way you have clean logs on your server, and you can watch for errors that are not supposed to be there.

The second part becomes less required though nice to have (in case of token invalidated on the server for other reasons than your 12:00am expiry, or due to time difference, other bugs etc), can also be handled with your GetToken method, if you are in the process of refreshing to the token store a flag to identify such, and that way calling functions will wait or retry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, there are some more doubts